# Sending email alert as soon as live data adds new row(s)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I'm new to Google sheets and scripting. I have set up a sheet to fetch live data using the IMPORTHTML function. I'm trying to setup a script and trigger to send me emails with the new row(S) information at (**@gmail.com) as soon as one or more new rows are added to the bottom in the live sheet. Is that possible? I have tried to write the code with a time based trigger to check every minute if a new row is added.

Below is the code I have currently. Two problems:
1. This is sending me emails every minute not when only new rows are added
2. This is sending me total number of rows not the information of the new row(s) added (I need it to send me details of all cells in the new row added)

Thanks much in advance.

```
 function sendemailupdates() {

 //setup function
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Email send"));
  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var StartRow = 2;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,11);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
  var lastRow = ActiveSheet.getLastRow();


  var message = "";
 //iterate loop
 for (i in AllValues) {

    //set current row
 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];


 //define column to check if sent
 var EmailSent = CurrentRow[11];

    //if row has been sent, then continue to next iteration
 if (EmailSent == "Sent") 
     continue;

 //set HTML template for information
 message +=
      "<p><b>New Row: </b>" + lastRow + "</p>";

     //set the row to look at
  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

   //mark row as "sent"
  ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 11).setValue("sent");
}

  //define who to send grants to 
 var SendTo = "**@gmail.com";

   //set subject line
 var Subject = "New row added";

  //send the actual email  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});
  Logger.log(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. This is sending me emails every minute not when only new rows are added**

You prolly set the trigger to go off every minute. The program is only doing what you tasked it to do. Check [Drive API Push Notifications](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=drive+push+notifications&oq=drive+push+notifications&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0j69i60j69i65j69i60.2439j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) tutorial on how to implement notifications when a change occurs in your resources.

**2. This is sending me total number of rows not the information of the new row(s) added (I need it to send me details of all cells in the new row added)**

You can check my code [here](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=drive+push+notifications&oq=drive+push+notifications&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0j69i60j69i65j69i60.2439j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Hopefully, it gives you insight to get you started on your work.

Comment: Thanks noogui. I will do the tutorial. On the code, I think you have the hyperlink wrong. 
And just to confirm, in your code, you have updated my script or is it a different code for something else for reference? Pardon me if some of these questions are basic.